# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace spring-batch

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-batch

I have to run a Spring batch job in a loop.

So my Main class is as below:

```
package com.mypackage.batch;

public class myApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] springConfig  = {"spring/batch/jobs/myJob.xml"};

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("myJob");       

     // read the file containing accountIds
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]))) {
        String account;
        while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {

            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("someParam", someParam).toJobParameters();
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    context.close();
}
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Eclipse.

Now I want to run this on server. For this I want to create an executable jar.

I am creating it as below using maven assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.batch.myApp</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This creates a jar with dependencies say `myBatch-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

However, when I run the following command:

```
java -jar myBatch-jar-with-dependencies.jar abc.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
    Jun 04, 2017 12:25:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4edde6e5: startup date [Sun Jun 04 12:25:40 AWST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 04, 2017 12:25:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/myJob.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/myJob.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at com.mypackage.batch.myApp.main(myApp.java:17)
```

My schema definitions in spring batch xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

And the dependencies in my pom is:

```
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring jdbc, for database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Inside your jar, in META-INF directory in `spring.handlers` file, can you check whether spring-batch namespace handler is present?

Comment: Why are you not using Spring Boot and java configuration?

Comment: @MichaelMinella: Because I could not figure out how can I run a Spring Batch job in a loop like I am doing in my example above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your namespace declaration, just change:
`http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd`  to be:
`http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd`, and it should work fine.

Otherwise you'll need to bake in custom `spring.schemas` files into your META-INF folder.

In the custom `spring.schemas` file you'd need something along the lines of this to map `spring-batch.xsd` to `spring-batch-3.0.xsd`:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd=org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
```